# Making a program that sums up only even numbers entered from console

Tags: c#

In one of my classes I was given an assignment to write a simple program that combines multiple numbers entered from the console, but only adding up the even ones. I was able to do the summing up part pretty easily but I can't figure out how to check for even numbers! If anyone can figure out how or explain for a beginner how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the full code so far:

```
using System;

namespace Test_3

{

    class Program
    
{

        static void Main(string[] args)
        
{
           
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of numbers n = ");
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers:");
            var sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                
                if (sum%2 == 0)
                {
                  
                }
                else
                {
                    
                }
                
                var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                sum = sum + num;
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of the numbers is  " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (num % 2 == 0)`? You seem to already know this, but you're instead applying it to `sum` to do nothing, rather than `num` as you indicate you want.

Comment: Also, you should never use `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`. the single most important rule in software development is **Never trust user input.** Use `int.TryParse` instead, unless you want to have your program crash every time the user enters `qwe` instead of `123`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem not to get the idea of an `if`-clause, let me explain this, using the following pieces of code:

Your code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (sum%2 == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
            
            var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sum = sum + num;
        }
```

This calculates the sum of all numbers (you check whether a number is even or not, but you don't use that information).

My proposal: (you check if a number is even, and you use that information)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (sum%2 == 0)
            {
            var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sum = sum + num;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
```

Another one, how to calculate the sum of the odd numbers? (Here you check if a number is even, but you use the case where it is not)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (sum%2 == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sum = sum + num;
            }
        }
```

So, you see? You can use `if`-clauses to filter out what you want to do when a condition is met or when a condition is not met, that's the whole idea behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to already know how to get the even numbers but here is how to apply it!

```
Console.WriteLine("Amount of numbers n = ");
var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers:");
var sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //first read a number from the console
     if (num % 2 == 0) //then check if it is even
     {
          sum = sum + num; //if it is, then add it to sum       
     }
 }

 Console.WriteLine("The sum of the numbers is  " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the variable num is divisible by two instead of the sum. The code you have checks if the sum is even and if so does nothing since you didn't add anything to the if statement. Instead, you should be doing `if ( num % 2 == 0)` .

You also need to move where num is declared to the top of the for loop and move the part where you add to the sum to the inside of the conditional (The if statement).